# 3D stopped working 11.10, Intel drivers

Tags: 11.10, intel-graphics

Now I can't get to the lightdm screen.

I had this problem, and I tried to fix this according to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67792/3d-not-working-anymore-on-11-10-with-intel-drivers).
Before I did this move, I was able actually to log in to unity 2d and gnome shell.
How do i undo the commands I followed, that got things worse. and how I can get 3D again?

note: several days ago, I had an update of xorg that failed.

Comment: Do you mean Unity 3D by 3D?

Comment: Is this a fresh install or was it an upgrade? Did you have installed the drivers from xorg-edgers?

Answer (score 1):

You dont give enough info, but still.
 
Try to remove the ppa of xorg-edgers. Uninstall the intel driver. (Easiest way for me is to install synaptic and search for the intel driver package).
 
Restart - hopefully Ubuntu will fall back to default driver.
 
In synaptic , install the drivers again - since you have removed the xorg-edgers ppa, ubuntu should install the default drives that came with the system.
 
 
Please, make backup with clonezilla live CD before doing this(or anytime you fiddle your system) - this could save you lot of time and trouble, check it out.
 
[CLONEZILLA](http://clonezilla.org/)